# Get data from a ManyToMany relationship with Doctrine2

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, relationship

I have the following relationship N:N between teachers table and groups table, where there is a third teachers_groups table.

I want to list the teachers bring me all the groups that this teacher teaches (** that is related **), but when I get the return of all teachers, `$teacher->getClasses()` is empty.

Here my code:

**Teacher Controller:**

```
namespace App\Controllers;

class TeacherController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->teachers = $this->model->getRepository()->findAll();
        // Bring all teachers, but does not bring their groups
        // with $teachers->getGroups()
        foreach ($this->teachers as $teachers) {
            var_dump($teachers->getGroups()); die();
        }
    }
}
```

**Teacher Entity:**

```
namespace App\Entities;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection as ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="teachers")
 */
class Teacher
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     **/
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", mappedBy="teachers")
     **/
    private $groups;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setGroups($groups)
    {
        $this->groups = $groups;
    }

    public function getGroups()
    {
        return $this->groups;
    }
}
```

**Group Entity:**

```
namespace App\Entities;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection as ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="groups")
 */
class Group
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     **/
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Teacher")
     * @JoinTable(name="teachers_groups",
     * joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_group",referencedColumnName="id")},
     * inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_teacher", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     **/
    private $teachers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->teachers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setTeachers($teachers)
    {
        $this->teachers = $teachers;
    }

    public function getTeachers()
    {
        return $this->teachers;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it's the missing `inversedBy="groups"` in Group->teachers. If adding it doesn't help, print out `$sql` in `BasicEntityPersister::getManyToManyStatement()` just before `return $this->conn->executeQuery($sql, $params, $types);` to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you're not referencing namespaces correctly in your Doctrine annotations.

Solution 1:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Teacher")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="teachers_groups",
...
```

or Solution 2:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToMany;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinTable;
...
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Teacher")
 * @JoinTable(name="teachers_groups",
...
```

In other words, your annotations are currently ignored. I'm surprised your teacher repository even recognizes the Teacher class as an entity.

Comment: I followed the example of their own documentation: **`http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html`**. And get without problems my entities, including other crud student and class that has 1:1 relationship. The Annotations are OK. Unless missing something about the relationship.